# JQuery TypeError is not a function

Tags: jquery

Trying to hide every element that has a class of 'shopping-item__checked'. Keeps getting thrown error that $(...).closest(...).find(...).hasClass(...).hide is not a function.

Thanks for the help in advanced,

```
function handleCheckBox() {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function(event) {
    if ($('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked')) {     
            console.log('it is checked');
            $(this).closest('.container').find('.js-shopping-item').hasClass('shopping-item__checked').hide();
    } else {
        renderShoppingList();
    }})
}
```

Comment: `. hasClass()` returns a boolean. `$(this).closest('.container').find('.js-shopping-item.shopping-item__checked').hide()`

Comment: got it, i was "hiding" a truthy statement. thank you

Answer (score 2):

> Try This

```
function handleCheckBox() {
        $('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function(event) {
        if ($('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked')) {     
                console.log('it is checked');
            if($(this).closest('.container').find('.js-shopping-item').hasClass('shopping-item__checked')){
                        $(this).closest('.container').find('.js-shopping-item').hide();
                }
        } else {
            renderShoppingList();
        }})
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code will be helpful to you,

```
function handleCheckBox() {
        $('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function(event) {
        if ($('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked')) {     
                console.log('it is checked');
                var $item = $(this).closest('.container').find('.js-shopping-item');
                if($item.hasClass('shopping-item__checked')){
                       $item.hide();
                }
        } else {
            renderShoppingList();
        }})
    }
```